# Exception thrown when opening a Excel spreedsheet from C# stating file is being used by another user

Tags: c#, excel

I am currently developing an application that requires an excel spreadsheet, location selected by the user, to be read into a DataTable and then stored in a sql server database.

The  application works perfectly in my development environment, however when it is deployed into my production environment an exception is thrown with the following message.

The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file '.xls'.  It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data.

My code to read the excel file is as follows:

```
OleDbConnection objConn = null;

DataSet objDataset1 = null;

string fileLocation = GetFileLocation();

string sConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
+ "Data Source=" + fileLocation
+ ";" + "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";

objConn = new OleDbConnection(sConnectionString);

objConn.Open(); //This is where the exception is thrown

OleDbCommand objCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", objConn);

OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter();

objAdapter1.SelectCommand = objCmdSelect;

objDataset1 = new DataSet();

objAdapter1.Fill(objDataset1, "XLData");

DataTable dt = objDataset1.Tables["XLData"];
```

Note the application and excel file are on different servers in the same domain.

Digging around various forumns and knowledge bases it would appear that the exception is thrown when the "user" does not have permission to use the file. Although not recommended permissions on the file have been set to Full Access for all users.

Apart from file permissions what else could cause this exception to be thrown?

Comment: Firewall settings, the file might actually be in use, etc.  Does this run successfully when executed on the remote machine (so that the file access is local to that machine).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is helpful but...

The error:

> The Microsoft Jet database engine
>   cannot open the file '.xls'.

seems to point to a file named `.xls`, as opposed to something named, say `myspreadsheet.xls` or `prodfile.xls`.

It may be a long shot, but can you do some debugging to make sure that the file Jet is trying to open actually exists? It may be that the filename is not being constructed properly, for some reason.

Comment: I'd recommend throwing in a File.Exists check and throw a FileNotFoundException if not found, just to make sure the pathing is correct.

Comment: Opps should have reviewed the question before I hit submit. the '.xls' is actually the fully qualified path to the file.

The location string being used is similar to

\\serverName\Tools\TestFiles\import.xls

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few answers to the same root problem:

[Read from Excel using OleDb in a Windows Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849602/read-from-excel-using-oledb-in-a-windows-service)

Answer (score 1):

kill the previous opened excel process before starting the new process for reading the excel.it will solve your problem.

i wrote one function you can call it before opening the xls.

```
private void kill_excel_process()
    {      
        foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (clsProcess.ProcessName.Equals("EXCEL"))
            {
                clsProcess.Kill();
                break;
            }
        }
     }
```