# C# Best way to read a XLS (XLSX) file and populate a datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, excel

What is the best (free or paid for) to read Excel files (XLS and XLSX) using C# and populate a datagrid, I would also like to have any changes made in the datagrid be written back to the file.

I should also add that it needs to be high performing as the datagrid can contain a significant number of rows (10,000+).

This would be used for a commercial application so it would need to be distributable.

This is a Windows Forms application.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend databinding the datagrid to a dataset/datatable populated via the ADO.NET OleDb provider.

You'll find an example at [Read from Excel using OleDb in a Windows Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849602/read-from-excel-using-oledb-in-a-windows-service)

I also found [How To Use ADO with Excel Data from Visual Basic or VBA](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819) and [How To Use ADOX with Excel Data from Visual Basic or VBA](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303814/EN-US/) to be useful in knowing how to create a table (sheet) and access sheets and ranges.

It works very well for xls files. I haven't tried using it for xlsx.

Answer (score 2):

[SmartXLS for .Net](http://www.smartxls.com)

It support read/write xls/xlsx files and can import/export workbook datas to/from a datagrid.

Answer (score 1):

You don't define whether you speak about web or fat client application.

You can use Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office for reading XLSX file. (see http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c6e744e5-36e9-45f5-8d8c-331df206e0d0&displaylang=en and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc850837(v=office.14).aspx for some examples and also on http://openxmldeveloper.org/default.aspx.)

You can display and allow to modify the content in a grid like jqGrid (see http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6) if you use a Web application. This grid is the best jQuery plugin which has a lot of different features and allow implement practical every scenario.

After all you can use Open XML SDK to save result in a modified XLSX file.

Answer (score 1):

For xlsx :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332058%28v=office.12%29.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/OpenXML.aspx